# Combox Display member Not Showing using list Object c#

Tags: combobox, objectdatasource

Here is the obj def:

```
 class TestScanOrder
{
    public long OrderCodeField { get; set; }

    public long PatientCodeField { get; set; }

    public string PatientNameField { get; set; }

    public string PatientVal { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTimeField { get; set; }


    public TestScanOrder(DateTime dt,long order,long pateintCode,string patientName,string patientVal)
    {
        DateTimeField = dt;
        OrderCodeField = order;
        PatientCodeField = pateintCode;
        PatientNameField = patientName;
        PatientVal = patientVal;
    }
```

And list is

`TestScanOrder[] list = new TestScanOrder[]{
                new TestScanOrder(  Convert.ToDateTime("06/24/2015"), 1910,  65547,  "Raja",  65547 + "~" + 1910 + "~" + 1 ),
                new TestScanOrder(Convert.ToDateTime("06/25/2015"), 1911,  65548, "Roja",  65548 + "~" + 1911 + "~" + 1 ),
                new TestScanOrder( Convert.ToDateTime("06/26/2015"),  1912,  65549,  "Peter",  65549 + "~" + 1912 + "~" + 2 ),
                new TestScanOrder( Convert.ToDateTime("06/27/2015"),  1913,  65550, "jaya",  65550 + "~" + 1913 + "~" + 2 ),
                new TestScanOrder(Convert.ToDateTime("06/28/2015"),  1914, 65551,  "Vijaya", 65551 + "~" + 1914 + "~" + 1 )
                };`

`cbPatients.DisplayMember = "PatientName";

cbPatients.DataSource = list;

cbPatients.ValueMember = null;`

However when I fire above  this is all I am getting:

[image]

How Can get the PatientName in combobox 
Please help me out these problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "TestScanOrder" class the property for patient name is "PatientNameField", so use the following to specify the display member of the combo box -

```
cbPatients.DisplayMember = "PatientNameField";
```

When invalid property name is specified for display member, the code will not break, and instead populate the combo with the fully qualified name of the class in data source.

Comment: @SathyaV: Its great the solution worked for you. Thanks. You can always mark the response as helpful or as answer if it worked you. It would be helpful for others as well.